# Change phpbb3.1 style to twig syntax

Tags: twig, phpbb3

Recording to [this](https://www.phpbb.com/styles/create/#a-twig), version 3.1 of phpBB should parse their old syntax to twig style now. I would like to use the parsed twig files to create a new style. I guess they can be found in the cache folder, but thats not very comfortable to reuse.

So Iam looking for the method that parses the old style to the knew one and to use it on the original files. I couldn't find it yet by just crawling through the sourcecode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself. Its in the `phpBB3/phpbb/template/twig/lexer.php` file.

To use the class standalone, just remove

```
extends \Twig_Lexer
```

and replace

```
return parent::tokenize($code, $filename);
```

by

```
return $code;
```

Then you can run

```
$lexer = new lexer();
echo $lexer->tokenize($originalTemplateCode); 
//returns template-code in twig-style syntax
```

Of course, thats a dirty hacked solution, but as long you only need it once to change the basic style for using it, its ok to do so